# MVC 3 and Xml property data in your model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xml-serialization

Does MVC 3 support Xml data?  I have a model class with a field (call it 'MyCustomersXml'), and I want to stuff it into a hidden field.  The issue I'm having is that I get a 500 error when the user clicks a submit button.  If the field is null, nothing happens.

I know ASP.Net does some type of validation by default to prevent html style content in control values, so my question is **does MVC 3 also share this behavior?  If so, how do I bypass this behavior to allow Xml in the postback?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could decorate this field with the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[AllowHtml]
public string MyCustomersXml { get; set; }
```

Now the ASP.NET framework will no longer throw an exception when you try to POST dangerous characters such as `<` and `>` in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Using the AllowHtml in MVC 3 will also expose you to a CSRF attack. To tighen your net and stop most CSRF attacks remember to use the AntiForgeryToken.

The following link contains a brief discussion and examples:
http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2011/09/03/simple-mvc3-ajax-feedback-form-with-antiforgerytoken-to-prevent-most-csrf-attacks/